# how to set null with updateByPrimaryKeySelective by config in mybatis generator

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

this is my batis generator file:

```xml
<table tableName="jxc_stock_journal" enableCountByExample="true"
            enableSelectByPrimaryKey="true" enableSelectByExample="true"
            enableUpdateByPrimaryKey="true" enableDeleteByPrimaryKey="true"
            enableInsert="true" domainObjectName="JxcStockJournal">
            <generatedKey column="id" sqlStatement="MySql"
                identity="true" />
</table>
```

so it will generate the mapper xml file. with null check in `updateByPrimaryKeySelective` method:
[image]

and I need to set some field to null with `updateByPrimaryKeySelective`, how to do it?

Comment: Don't use screenshots to convey essential parts of the question. According to SO rules plain text should be used and screenshots can be used only as an addition to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "updateByPrimaryKey" method to set a null value. As you've seen, you can do that with "updateByPrimaryKeySelective".

Comment: yes I knew. but my situation is that I need to set some fields to `null`, and also need to  ignore the field I did't set. so both `updateByPrimaryKey` and `updateByPrimaryKeySelective` are not good for me.

Comment: This legacy generated code is all or nothing, so it won't work in this situation. I suggest you take a look at the new runtime for MyBatis Dynamic SQL. That code has far more capabilities and it would be much easier to create the kind of updates you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
int updateByExampleSelective(@Param("record") PriceActivityApplyDO record, @Param("example") PriceActivityApplyExample example, @Param("selective") PriceActivityApplyDO.Column ... selective);
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer.